# Sandcastle links to C# interface from welcome page

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I have successfully built a help file of my C# solution using a SandCastle project.

In the SandCastle project there is a Welcome page.

I wish to have a link from this welcome page to a page in the help file.

The Sandcastle doco on links says I ought to use the GUID to the topic Id

But my generated Help file doesn't have topic Id for the section I wish to go to.

I viewed the source to ascertain this.

So how can I create a link to the help page that I wish to go to?

I tried this, but it is not a link:

```
 <para>
      <link xlink:href="e0b76020-d63f-a2e9-5219-3dfc990041c0.htm">IBillingExtractionService</link>
 </para>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links to other conceptual topics are created by using the link element. As shown in the sample snapshot just specify the GUID and don't use the extension as a suffix.

As you can see the `<relatedTopics>` tag is resulting in a **See Also** section.

Please note to use the [Entity References tool window](http://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/e49eea91-a9ef-4aa5-ad8f-16ebd61b798a.htm) as shown in my snapshot to insert such links into your topics in an easy way by drag & drop.

[image]